# Postgresql link query same table

Tags: postgresql, hyperlink

I have read many answers here but this is my first question. I am a newbie so suggestions about question style/format are appreciated.

PostgreSQL 9.1
I have one table called events. primarykey=serialid

```
   ==============================================
   |serialid|             time|sender|dependency|

   |       1| 2012-11-22 14:40|  John|          |
   |       2| 2012-11-22 14:41|   Sue|         1|
   |       3| 2012-11-22 14:42|  John|         1|
   |       4| 2012-11-22 14:43|   Sue|          |
   |       5| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
   |       6| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
```

About the table:
The first row(serialid==1) has 2 dependent events: 2nd,3rd

(1)FIRST GOAL
I would like to ensure that if I make a WHERE statement ex: WHERE sender="John" every dependent event also exist in the result table

bad result:

```
   |       1| 2012-11-22 14:40|  John|          |
   |       3| 2012-11-22 14:42|  John|         1|
   |       5| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
   |       6| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
```

I also need Sue's event(serialid==2) because it is connected to John "main event"

good result:

```
   |       1| 2012-11-22 14:40|  John|          |
   |       2| 2012-11-22 14:41|   Sue|         1|
   |       3| 2012-11-22 14:42|  John|         1|
   |       5| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
   |       6| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
```

(2)SECOND GOAL: lets look at the "good result" table:

```
   |       1| 2012-11-22 14:40|  John|          |
   |       2| 2012-11-22 14:41|   Sue|         1|
   |       3| 2012-11-22 14:42|  John|         1|
   |       5| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
   |       6| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
```

There are events without "main event". Events with serialid: 5,6 is a dependent of event serialid: 4 but it is not in thre result. The good result would be:

```
   |       1| 2012-11-22 14:40|  John|          |
   |       2| 2012-11-22 14:41|   Sue|         1|
   |       3| 2012-11-22 14:42|  John|         1|
   |       4| 2012-11-22 14:43|   Sue|          |
   |       5| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
   |       6| 2012-11-22 14:44|  John|         4|
```

(SUMMARY)
So I need a query where I can specify a custom where statement and the rest of the query collects all the dependents of the result of the where statement.

something like this:

SELECT * FROM events WHERE "my conditions"

UNION??
magic dependency collector query :-)

(NOTE)
dependency can be only one level deep.

Thank you in advance,
Dave

**UPDATE**

Thanks for Igor I got my real query in my real database:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dep_event AS 
(
  SELECT ev.serialid,ev.time_processed,ev.time_created,ev.sender_console,ev.sender_manager,ev.sender_map,ev.sender_device,ev.event_type,ev.event_command,ev.event_severity,ev.event_actionlist,ev.event_source,ev.event_info,ev.event_message,ev.dependency_main,ev.dependency_comment
  FROM events ev
  WHERE ev.event_severity='warning'
  UNION
  SELECT ev.serialid,ev.time_processed,ev.time_created,ev.sender_console,ev.sender_manager,ev.sender_map,ev.sender_device,ev.event_type,ev.event_command,ev.event_severity,ev.event_actionlist,ev.event_source,ev.event_info,ev.event_message,ev.dependency_main,ev.dependency_comment
  FROM  events ev
  JOIN dep_event dev ON ev.serialid = dev.dependency_main
             OR dev.serialid = ev.dependency_main
)
SELECT *
FROM dep_event
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE

```
"CTE Scan on dep_event  (cost=203955680.32..204419627.58 rows=23197363 width=1034) (actual time=11.204..4602.977 rows=234159 loops=1)"
"  CTE dep_event"
"    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..203955680.32 rows=23197363 width=176) (actual time=11.200..4468.402 rows=234159 loops=1)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on events ev  (cost=0.00..47382.98 rows=227693 width=176) (actual time=11.181..2145.798 rows=225365 loops=1)"
"                Filter: ((event_severity)::text = 'warning'::text)"
"          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=4.89..20344435.01 rows=2296967 width=176) (actual time=1.593..610.347 rows=5863 loops=3)"
"                ->  WorkTable Scan on dep_event dev  (cost=0.00..45538.60 rows=2276930 width=16) (actual time=0.050..33.360 rows=78053 loops=3)"
"                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events ev  (cost=4.89..8.90 rows=1 width=176) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=234159)"
"                      Recheck Cond: ((serialid = dev.dependency_main) OR (dev.serialid = dependency_main))"
"                      ->  BitmapOr  (cost=4.89..4.89 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=234159)"
"                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on serialid  (cost=0.00..2.44 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=234159)"
"                                  Index Cond: (serialid = dev.dependency_main)"
"                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on dep_main  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=234159)"
"                                  Index Cond: (dev.serialid = dependency_main)"
"Total runtime: 4621.138 ms"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general - it is a clear case of recursive CTE (`WITH RECURSIVE` statement).

It would look like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE dep_event AS (
  SELECT ev.serialid, ev.time, ev.sender, ev.dependency
  FROM events ev
  WHERE ev.sender = 'John' -- start condition here
  UNION
  SELECT ev.serialid, ev.time, ev.sender, ev.dependency
  FROM  events ev
  JOIN dep_event dev ON ev.serialid = dev.dependency -- connect conditions here
                     OR dev.serialid = ev.dependency
)
SELECT *
FROM dep_event;
```

Additional information here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

This `RECURSIVE` query will handle any level of dependencies.

UPD: Fixed some mistakes in the query and created SQLFiddle example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4e915/4

Comment: Thank you Igor this is exactly what I needed.
Unfortunately the query runs very slowly. Do you have any idea to speed it up, indexing? remove recursive?

Comment: @David Molnar Can you provide `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` of the query?

Comment: My example is simplified the real database has more columns and different names. I have created an index on dependency and the query became much more faster. It is good now. Of course I can provide you the Query plan. My answer is fully answered, anyway do you need the query plan?

Comment: I needed the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to help you with query performance. If you are satisfied with current query performance - I do not need the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` any more.

Comment: I am satisfied. Just for fun and study I have attached the explain analyze